# How add Manifest.xml on gitignore to not push

Tags: android, github, gitignore

I'm creating a project with react-native and have the folder android,
inside there's file android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml where I have my google api key and I don't want to push this file just once, when I import to project, then I add this path on .gitignore but it doesn't ignore.

how should I put the path on the file gitignore to not push this file ?

Answer (score 2):

In your project level `.gitignore` file add the following line:

`android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the project level .gitignore and then push